# how to tell the difference between a normal user and a bot using code (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

(discord.py) I am making a command for a bot for one specific server. This command will make a statistics channel with the number of members, the number of bots, and the total amount of everybody including members and bots on the server.
I have a little bit of code for now, but I need help with the bots:

```
@client.tree.command(name='stats', description='set up stats for the server (for sheepie or airone only)')
async def stats(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  members = len(client.users)
```

I have tried nothing because I have no idea how to do this.
All I need is someone to tell me how to distinguish the bots from the normal users/people.

Comment: The [user class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id1) provides the boolean attribute `bot` to distinguish meat from silicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone in the comments said, *the `discord.User` class provides the attribute `bot` to identify bot users.*

As for the code, `len(client.users)` will return the count of **all** the users your bot can see in **every** server it is and it includes bots. [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20users#discord.Client.users)

I'm going to recommend something like this for counting bots and users separately in the guild the command was called from:

```
@client.command(name='stats', description='set up stats for the server (for sheepie or airone only)')
async def stats(ctx):
    # Create empty lists
    members = []
    bots = []
    # For loop that checks if the user is a bot and appends it to the right list
    async for user in ctx.guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
        if user.bot:
            bots.append(user)
        else:
            members.append(user)
    # Get the number of members and bots
    memberNum = len(members)
    botNum = len(bots)
```

And if you don't want the members and bots to be stored in tables and just want the number:

```
@client.command(name='stats', description='set up stats for the server (for sheepie or airone only)')
async def stats(ctx):
    # Create the counters
    membersCount = 0
    botsCount = 0
    # For loop that increments the counters based on if the user is a bot or not
    async for user in ctx.guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
        if user.bot:
            botsCount += 1
        else:
            membersCount += 1
```

Note that if you have many users in your server it can be a little slow because it's going through every user in the guild.

Additionally, you can use `guild.members` instead of `guild.fetch_members()`. The difference is that `guild.fetch_members()` is an API call and `guild.members` is a property. This could fix the slowness problem if there is too much members in your server.

[API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_members)

Hope I helped you in making your discord bot!

Comment: I tried both of those and got the same error: 
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\Users\e\OneDrive\Documents\.midnight\main.py", line 36, in stats
    for user in interaction.guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

Comment: Hey, so I tried my solution with a prefix command instead of an app command (bc I got rate limited for making app commands XD) and it worked by adding `async` before the start of the for loop declaration. I can't check how it is with app_commands but it should be the same. I'm going to edit my answer with the working solution but if the app command does not work for you try making a `@app_commands.command()` decorator instead of `@client.tree.command()` you need to import `app_commands` from `discord` for this. Try all that and tell us if it works.  And remember to sync the tree before testing